# Checking username and hashed/salted password in mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords, salt

When validating user logins, is it safe to first search for the username and THEN if found, retrieve the hashed password and salt and compare it with the user input?

Or, should the salt for the user-inputed username be retrieved by itself, then be hashed with the inputed password and compared with the final hash in the database?

In essence, is it safe to store a password for an inputed username from a database before knowing whether the password the user entered is valid?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the examples of the PHP Password Hashing API https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat the answer is: No, you read the user from the database and compare the stored password hash with the password you just got from the login form.

And please try to use this library - PHP 5.5 will support the functions natively, and if you are on PHP 5.3.7 and later, it sounds like a very good idea not to reinvent the wheel and simply use these functions. Doing your own thing is more likely to be attackable.

Comment: But in which case, wouldn't I have to do 2 database queries? The first to retrieve the salt on the row of the username, and the second to compare the now salted and hashed user-inputed password with the one in the database.

Comment: @Sam - No you make one query with the username and get the password-hash `SELECT passwordhash FROM user WHERE user.name = 'Sam'`. Afterwards, if a row with this username was found, you can compare the password-hash from the db, with the entered password. The salt is usually part of the password-hash and you compare it with the hashed user input (do the hashing in PHP and not with database functions).

Answer (score 1):

You may check both loginname and password at the same time. Get the raw password; salt it, then check if salted password and username combination exist.  Ofcourse, password in db should have been salted and hashed before.

```
 if($loginname AND $loginpass){
  $loginpass=sha1($salt1.$loginpass.$salt2,$raw_output=false );

    $userinfo_query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$loginname' AND user_pass='$loginpass' LIMIT 1";

  }
```

Comment: You cannot know the salt for the password if you did not read the user from the database. And you know you should use an individual salt for each user, don't you?

Comment: @Sven, salt might be anything, not just a username. and the username might be taken from the session if it is saved. there's millions of ways to salt.

Comment: Yes, but there will be only one reasonable way to hash passwords in PHP in the future. And SHA1 is NOT a reasonable hashing function for passwords.